# Read fragment parameter from redirect url using javascript

Tags: javascript, url-parameters, apple-sign-in

I want to read the parameters attached as fragments to the redirect url . I understood that we cannot fetch fragments using jsp but is there any way I could get the parameters using JavaScript?

Eg: `http://localhost:880/redirectUrl/index.jsp#code=1&id=30`

I want to fetch code and id values.

Comment: Are you doing this on the client or server? On the client it's in `location.hash`. It's not sent to the server.

Comment: if you want them sent to the server, you should use query parameters, not fragments.

Comment: @Bamar  it is actually the response being sent from apple . They append their response as fragment and hit my redirect url ( redirect url is a jsp file deployed at particular location)

Comment: You could add your own redirect. The client-side of index.jsp could grab the fragment, turn it into query parameters, and redirect to another URL that includes them.